# Return affected rows in while loop

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I make below code return me the affected (deleted) rows?
Do some kind of incrementation using `@@ROWCOUNT`?

```
public Task<int> DeleteAuditsOlderThan(DateTime timestamp)
{
    var query = @"
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @r INT;
        SET @r = 1;
        WHILE @r > 0
        BEGIN
           BEGIN TRANSACTION;
           DELETE TOP (10000) dbo.ForwardAudits
           WHERE Timestamp < {0};
           SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
           COMMIT TRANSACTION;
           CHECKPOINT
           WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
        END";

    return Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query, timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Look into the `OUTPUT` clause. *Side note `WHERE Timestamp < {0}` looks like injection, not parametrisation.*

Comment: Move the rows to a view.  Then return the view before deleting.

Comment: @Larnu Using EF Core to execute the query. I'm hoping it's not using `string.format`. In reality there is no problem because the value is calculated from another service. So only a problem if someone messes up or there is an intruder alert

Comment: @jdweng we are talking about millions of rows

Comment: *"So only a problem if someone messes up or there is an intruder alert"* So why not remove that problem? Just parametrise to start with...

Comment: You are correct, but not my main problem at the moment. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As I hoped, EF Core does take care of injection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0/#string-interpolation-in-fromsql-and-executesqlcommand

Comment: So what if the number of rows is over a million.  The server should be able to handle the temporary data.

Comment: `CHECKPOINT` is probably a bad idea, why do you feel it's necessary? The server will decide when to checkpoint automatically. Also with only one command, `BEGIN TRAN` `COMMIT` is also unnecessary

Comment: Not sure about CHECKPOINT. Read a post about deleting millions of rows, and adding CHECKPOINT would minimize the size of the log file. And I guess BEGIN TRAN COMMIT is so that I do commit in small chunks instead of one big. But to be honest, not sure. I do know that this code worked better than a regular DELETE. There is around 46M rows and I have to delete around 2M once a day.

Answer (score 2):

You need two variables: for current affected rows and total affected rows:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @r INT,
                @Cnt INT,
                @TimeStamp TIMESTAMP;--remove for parametrization
        SET @r = 1;
        SET @Cnt = 0;
        WHILE @r > 0
        BEGIN
           BEGIN TRANSACTION;
           DELETE TOP (10000) dbo.ForwardAudits
           WHERE Timestamp < @TimeStamp;
           SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
           SET @Cnt += @r;
           COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END
        SELECT @Cnt
```